# Unable to import 'app.xxx' with pylint (vscode, virtualenv)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, pylint

I'm trying to import one of my django apps but i receive this error:
   Unable to import 'apps.videoclub.views'pylint(E0401)

I'm working in a virtualenv

I already tried:

- Modify my pylintrc file with this:
  init-hook='import sys; sys.path.append("C:/Users/Angel/Desktop/Trabajos/videoclub_django_new/videoclub_django_new/videoclub_django/")'
  [pylintrc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZBrP.jpg)
- Modify my workspace settings with the absolute path
  [workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYUOV.jpg)
  I know that i can remove those errors but i want to do it the right way.

Maybe this image could be helpful

[context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cq9an.jpg)

Thank you guys!

Comment: I didnt put that image there for code. I wanted to show where the errors were. In code and terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You could either install pylint inside your virtual environment or use the [pylint-venv](https://pypi.org/project/pylint-venv/) package to use the system-installed pylint.

Comment: I already did that! pylint and python are both inside my virtualenv.